# Java params cannot be Resolved Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

For the following block of code I am getting errors that say:

```
    import com.agile.api.*;
    import java.util.*;


    public class AddBOM {
       public static final String        USERNAME = "blahblah";
       public static final String        PASSWORD = "1234";
       public static final String        URL      = "http://www";
       public static IAgileSession       session  = null;
       public static AgileSessionFactory factory;
       public static final String        parent   = "P1";
       public static final String        child1   = "P2";
       public static final String        child2   = "P3";

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          try {
             // Create an IAgileSession instance
             session = connect(session);
             // Create three parts
             IItem  itemParent = createItem(parent);
             IItem  itemChild1 = createItem(child1);
             IItem  itemChild2 = createItem(child2);
             // Add the child parts to the BOM table of the parent part
             ITable bomTable   = addBOM(itemParent, itemChild1, itemChild2);
          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
             session.close();
          }
       }

       /**
        * <p> Create an IAgileSession instance </p>
        *
        * @param session
        * @return IAgileSession
        * @throws APIException
        */
       private static IAgileSession connect(IAgileSession session)
                                 throws APIException {
      factory = AgileSessionFactory.getInstance(URL);
      HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
      map.put(AgileSessionFactory.USERNAME, USERNAME);
      map.put(AgileSessionFactory.PASSWORD, PASSWORD);
      session = factory.createSession(map);
      return session;
   }

       /**
        * <p> Create a part </p>
        *
        * @param parent
        * @return IItem
        * @throws APIException
        */
       private static IItem createItem(String number) throws APIException {
          IItem item = (IItem)session.createObject(ItemConstants.CLASS_PART, number);

          return item;
       }

       /**
        * <p> Add the child parts to the BOM table of the parent part </p>
        *
        * @param itemParent
        * @param itemChild1
        * @param itemChild2
        * @return ITable
        * @throws APIException
        */
       private static ITable addBOM(IItem itemParent, IItem itemChild1,
                                    IItem itemChild2) throws APIException {
          ITable table  = itemParent.getTable(ItemConstants.TABLE_BOM);
          IRow   row1   = table.createRow();
          String number = (String)itemChild1.getValue(ItemConstants.ATT_TITLE_BLOCK_NUMBER);

          row1.setValue(ItemConstants.ATT_BOM_ITEM_NUMBER, number);
          IRow row2 = table.createRow(itemChild2);

          return table;
       }
    }
```

I'm not sure what the problem is? This is an example from Oracle's SDK. I modified the params, but I still got the same, error that it cannot be resolved.

Comment: OK, where is `params` defined? Do you mean to use `map`? (Or for `map` to be called `params`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named your `HashMap` `map` not `params`. Make them match. Change

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

to something like,

```
Map<String, Integer> params = new HashMap<>();
```

**or** change the lines using `params` to use `map`.

```
map.put(AgileSessionFactory.USERNAME, USERNAME);
map.put(AgileSessionFactory.PASSWORD, PASSWORD);
session = factory.createSession(map);
```

Comment: Read my answer, and look at your `connect` method again.

Comment: Connection refused: connect

Comment: I think I'm closer now per the connection refuse message

Comment: Time to check the url you're trying to connect to; then check the username and password. I suggest stepping through it with your *debugger*.